# Editing sitemap dynamically in mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, sitemap, mvcsitemapprovider

In my `Asp.Net MVC3` application I am using `sitemap` .
I have some scenario that i want to `edit sitemap file dynamically` during run time.

I just tired `removing a node` and `adding a new one` instead of that.
I tried with following code

```
 SiteMapNode node = FindSiteMapNodeFromKey("test");
 SiteMapNode no = node.ParentNode;
 RemoveNode(node);
 mRootNode = new SiteMapNode(this, "Deleted Home", "Default.aspx", "Home");
 no.ChildNodes.Add(mRootNode);.
```

But the node became `null`. I have a sitemap node with key test in my sitemap

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Delete" action="Delete"  key="test" roles="testrole"/>
```

Any idea forachieving this properly will really helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

For editing the sitemap dynamically, you can either use a custom implementation of [IDynamicNodeProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-sitemap-nodes-using-IDynamicNodeProvider) or a custom implementation of [ISiteMapBuilder](http://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-sitemaps-using-ISiteMapBuilder).

The former is easier to do, the latter gives you more control over the nodes. Also, in order to use ISiteMapBuilder, you must use an external DI container so you can replace the built-in implementations with your own.

Note depending on how often you are updating the nodes, you may need to tweak the caching settings as well.